Looking for a Complete Online Collection of Fr. Jean Baptiste Saint-Jure's "The Knowledge and Love of Our Lord Jesus Christ"
According to the New Catholic Encyclopedia:

[Fr. Jean Baptiste] Saint–Jure had immediate success as a writer and exercised a profound influence upon the Christian piety of 17th-century France. His book on the life of the Baron of Renty went through seven editions by 1654, three years after its initial publication. His other published works include a treatise on the knowledge and love of Jesus (1634); meditations on the important truths of the faith, and on the purgative, illuminative, and unitive ways to perfection (1637); a treatise on the means for the main actions of the Christian life (1644); considerations on the crucified Savior (1643); a treatise in two volumes on the spiritual life (1646); meditations on the principal mysteries of Christ's life, also in two volumes (1653); a consideration of Christ's instructions to men (1649); a treatise on faith, hope, and charity (1646); and a treatise on the vows of religious life and the qualities necessary for living the community life of a religious (1658).

In particular, I have been searching for all volumes (there are at least two) of Saint-Jure's "The Knowledge and Love of Our Lord Jesus Christ." (in English preferably.)
So far, all I have been able to find is Volume II which was published in English in 1875.
I would like to locate Volume I, which I am hoping contains Saint-Jure's treatise on the Divine Will and our need to surrender to It.
More specifically, it is this treatise which appears in TAN's Trustful Surrender to Divine Providence along with some excerpts on the subject by St. Claude de la Columbiere.
As I said before, I don't know if there are additional volumes available in English, but if there are, I would very much like to have online access to them.
It seems that Saint-Jure's "The Knowledge and Love of Our Lord Jesus Christ" was continually at the fingertips of St. John Vianney (the Cure of Ars).
QUESTION: Where may I find an online (preferably English, but French OK) version of Volume I (and any others that may exist after Volume II) of Fr. Jean Baptiste Saint-Jure's The Knowledge and Love of Our Lord Jesus Christ? Internet Archive (or something like it) would be best for my purposes, as I would like to re-typeset at least some parts in English; and so, I am looking for online access to original (19th century or no later than 1929) publications of the volumes in PDF form.
Thank you.

There's an  ed. of vol. 1 and vol. 3, but they're rarer than vol. 2, the only digitized  volume of this work.
The  ed., De la connaissance et de l'amour du fils de Dieu notre seigneur Jésus Christ (1877), is 5 volumes:
1,
2,
3,
4,
5!
Part 1 of Trustful Surrender to Divine Providence seems to be an abridgement of what starts on p. 206 of vol. 2 of the  ed.
